# How do we pronounce "Universe"

Tags: pronunciation, transcription

Which is closer to the right transcription of the word "Universe"?

junɪvers or junɪvr̩s

> Do we actually pronounce the e that is before the r.

In other words, do we say vrse or v'e'rse

Comment: Most people *usually* enunciate the final vowel in ***universe*** the same as the vowel in, say, ***first, curse, hearse, worse***. But (particularly in rapid/relaxed speech) it can be reduced to the schwa **ə**. But it's always a **3** syllable word, so I don't think your second version above would pass muster..

Comment: SO, the first choice is correct

Comment: As any dictionary should tell you ([this one](https://www.macmillandictionary.com/pronunciation/british/universe), for example). I think this question is Off-Topic, in that it's a "basic" question of pronunciation involving no special subtleties.

Comment: @FumbleFingers Not any. Oxforddictionaries.com, for example, shows a schwa there. (So does MW, but I don't know if the schwa in their transcription is the same as the IPA's.)

Comment: I don't want to get bogged down in the difference between the short schwa **ə** and the long one **ɜː**. It's just a "neutral" vowel that may be shortened in relaxed speech (and the presence of an enunciated **/r/** only occurs in rhotic speech, which isn't mine).

Comment: I'm actually not sure, as a US English speaker, what it would even mean to "pronounce the e".  There's not really much difference to me between *ver* and *vrr*.

Comment: @stangdon: ***Um, Erm***. There's got to be at least a (usually, *neutral*) vowel there, whether or not the /r/ is enunciated.

Comment: @FumbleFingers - Well, sure. But my point is that a neutral vowel there is more or less practically indistinguishable from no vowel at all; consider *ger* vs. *grr*.

Comment: @stangdon: But apart from a few "non-vocalised sounds" such as the double tongue/cheek-click used to encourage a horse, or the exasperated "exclamation" sometimes transcribed as ***Tsk!*** or ***Tut!***, all English words *have* to have some kind of "vowel", even if it's just a schwa. But speaking for myself, I rarely if ever find it necessary (or even *possible*) to enunciate **/r/.**

Comment: @FumbleFingers - I see that you're from the Southeast UK, whereas I'm from New York City - I wonder if that explains some of our differences on the pronunciation!  I was wondering about your comment about enunciating /r/, but the different rhoticities of our dialects may explain it.

Comment: @stangdon: I always think of ***arse*** as the archetypal word where I have an /r/ but most Americans don't, but actually that's just a matter of orthography for me (I have no way of pronouncing ***pass*** and ***parse*** differently). Certainly in just about all other contexts, you might have ***r's*** where I only have ***Ah's***.

Comment: I don't think this question is "entirely answerable with a dictionary".  Dictionary transcriptions don't necessarily answer questions like "Is this an /ər/ sequence or just a syllabic /r̩/?" And they certainly don't explain what it would *mean* for it to be one or the other.  A good answer here would discuss whether the distinction is meaningful and what the *phonetic realization* of these phonemic sequences would be.  Then learners could apply that knowledge to other words in the future with similar transcriptions.

Comment: @snailboat Aye, you think that because it be true.

Comment: @stangdon think of a french speaker pronouncing 'Universe' in English with a french accent. That's what it means to pronounce the 'e', I believe.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to *Longman Dictionary of Contemporary English 5th edition*, *Collins Cobuild 6th edition*, and *Cambridge Advanced Learner's Dictionary 3rd edition*, there is a **/ər/** sound in Universe. That means we should pronounce the "e" before the "r".

**"Universe"**--again, according to these dictionaries--should rhyme with **verse**, **terse**, and **curse**.